# To much data is being worked on inside one html file (overload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

**Problem:**

The problem I am encountering is that my application is running in slow performance, because I have too many pages (page1.html, page2.html and page3.html) running inside one file (index.html), the point is to let the user decide which page he/she wants to view. I have tried different jQuery events, but none of them worked out for me.

What I am trying to achieve: Write a jQuery code that listens to which page the user clicks on and then display the diagram. I want only one diagram to be shown a time, and the rest must be completely idle.

**Index.html**: It consists of a navigation menu `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"..></div>` and with jQuery can be used to navigate between page1.html, page2.html and page3.html.

```
<html>
<head>
      <!--Library-->
</head>
<body>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a id = "DataOne" data-target="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      <li><a id = "DataTwo" data-target="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      <li><a id = "DataThree" data-target="3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

      <!--Display only one page at time-->
  <div id="page1"></div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
    <div id="page3"></div>
  </body>

    <script>
    $('[data-target]').on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
        if (target == 1) {
            $("#page1").load("page1.html");
        } else if(target == 2){
            $("#page2").load("page2.html");
        } else if(target == 3){ 
            $("#page3").load("page3.html");
        }
    }); 
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to look into AngularJS or similar framework instead of using jQuery.

Comment: @Freelancer, is there something specific you want me too look at? Because AngularJS is a very big subject.

Comment: Yes it is big. I was just thinking that AngularJS or other similar framework is better for making what you seem to make (a single page application). Because routing and attaching data to view are much easier. Of course there is a learning curve too.

Comment: @Freelancer, I will take a look at AngularJS.

Comment: I'm writing an answer right now for you how to do it in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunk: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/dMym8VSXNONGuFgls2p5?p=preview

And a modification of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!--Library-->
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a class="page-links" id="DataOne" data-target="1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true">Page 1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-links" id="DataTwo" data-target="2">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true">Page 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-links" id="DataThree" data-target="3">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true">Page 3</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Display only one page at time-->
    <div id="page"></div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.page-links').click(function() {
          $('#page').load('page' + $(this).data('target') + '.html');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Explanation of corrections:

- Your script tag was below  tag, when it should be above.
- jQuery is included now
- We wait for $(document).ready event, which means we'll know our document is ready when we try to listen to events such as click or apply changes to it, such as loading another page.

No need for multiple divs for different pages, we have one div (#page) where we load any sub-page we want.

Comment: Thank you, this satisfy the part where the user can navigate through pages he has clicked. But not the part where the page is running in the background. As I mentioned, I only want one page that can be viewed per time, the rest MUST BE COMPLETELY IDLE.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - do you want different pages (1, 2, 3...) to load into the div of the main page, or do you want to move from one page to another? (which you could achieve with simple links, no need for javascript).

Comment: I want different pages (1,2,3) to load. When I analyse the performance, I can see that page1 and page2 runs in slower fps individually. But if I only run page1, and delete page2 or vice-versa. Then the performance in page1 or page2 has increased dramatically.